# Convert a String to Image using Data URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, base64, data-uri

I have a requirement, where i need to take a string from html input control from the end User, and show the input text as an image using Javascript/Jquery.

I tried the below code, but it did not give me the image.

```
        var imgEncodedString = 'data:image/png;base64,' + btoa($('#txtName').val());

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        // added `width` , `height` properties to `img` attributes
        img.width = "250px";
        img.height = "250px";
        img.src = imgEncodedString ;
        var preview = document.getElementById("img_preview");
        preview.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: And how looks like user input `$('#txtName').val()`???

Comment: User input will be a name, for .e.g
A. Wolff

and the image will be exactly same, something similar to Print Screen of the User Input

Comment: Then you're on the wrong path. A little help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillText